# Forward all tcp packet is specific ip subnet to one destination

Tags: linux, proxy, openwrt

I want all packet to specific subnet as example `1.1.1.0/24` will redirect to one IP address `1.1.1.1`.
I have try with squid proxy.

```
acl test dst 1.1.1.0/24
http_access allow test
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.1 test
```

And got error message :

```
2023/10/09 21:17:23 kid1| commBind Cannot bind socket FD 12 to 1.1.1.1: (99) Cannot assign requested address
```

What other program can forward specific subnet to one destination, proxy program or anything, I want use for openwrt.